# Compare only specific bits of a number

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I am trying to do a comparison between two numbers, however I only want that the n-th bit of one of the numbers to be equal a certain binary value

ex: assert (5==0b1XX) == true 
since 5 is 0b101 and the 3rd MSB is 1

Is there anyway I can use a don't care (X) in javascript?

Comment: Search for bitwise operators

Comment: Yes, you're looking for `(5 & 0b100) !== 0`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work because I am using a function someone else has written and it does not allow me to manipulate the var to be compared. As I said, the only thing that might work is a 'don't care'.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you can and can't do. The `&` operator does the "don't care" operation that you describe, so if you can't use it then I don't see how you could use anything else either.

Comment: @NathaliaDellaGiustinaBallma No, there is no number value that contains "don't care" bits which are used for an `==` operation.

Comment: @NathaliaDellaGiustinaBallma while there isn't a "don't care" bit in javascript, you can still compare the n-th bit of a number using `>>` and `&`. Check my answer below for an example and a function that does it for you.

Comment: @hermbit thanks for your help! I am familiar with masks and bitwise operations. I'll use them in a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise **SHIFT** `>>` along with bitwise **AND** `&` to achieve this.

```
// SHIFT off the first two bits, then check the first bit with AND
(0b101 >> 2 & 1) === 1
```

`>>` will shift bits to the right and discard any bits shifted off.

`&` will return a 1 when the corresponding bits are both `1`.

[Here is the MDN page on bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators).

**Here is a function you can use for any value in any position:**

```
// returns true if 'target' has a 'value' at 'position'
function checkBit(target, position, value) {
    return (target >> (position - 1) & 1) === value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@hermbit is right. I'll take a shot at explaining it too.

You can shift the bit representation of a number by using the `>>` operator.

So if you have the number 5 `0b101` and you shift it two places you get `0b001` (removed last two places and filled left side with 0s.

Then you can use the `&` to make a logical and of both numbers. In this case

`0b001 & 0b001` is equal to `0b001`, because it will return a number where the bits will be `1` only in the places where both numbers are `1`.

I hope this clarifies things.